# Accelerate reading/processing log files in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, large-data, large-files, file-read

I am trying to read a large log files (around 10G) with the following format:

```
3 49
7 28 
...
```

Basically we have two columns, each column is an positive integer.

And here is the code I am using to read the log files into a two-level map:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>>> coverage_info;

coverage_info cmap;
...

      fp = fopen("log.txt", "r");

      while (fgets(line, len, fp)) {
        sscanf(line, "%d %d", &func_id, &bb_id);

        auto it = cmap.find(func_id);
        if (it != cmap.end()) {
          auto it1 = (it->second).find(bb_id);
          if (it1 != (it->second).end()) {
            auto c =std::get<0>(cmap[func_id][bb_id]);
            cmap[func_id][bb_id] = std::make_tuple(++c, 0, 0);
          }
          else 
            cmap[func_id][bb_id] = std::make_tuple(1, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
          std::unordered_map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>> m;
          m[bb_id] = std::make_tuple(1, 0, 0);
          cmap[func_id] = m;
        }
      }
```

When reading a 7G log files, the above code takes about 30 mins to finish, which is too slow for me.

I have thought about the following ways of optimization:

1. use `unordered_map` instead of `map` to speedup the `find` from `log(n)` to `O(1)`. And this reduces the processing time from 30mins to about 15 mins for my case.
2. maybe sort the log file first --> but since using `unordered_map` is a good option for me, sorting the log file does not make too much sense right now?
3. try to read a buffer (e.g., 10M) instead of one line per `fgets`? Maybe I can use a `std::ifstream` or something with a large buffer?
4. use `mmap`? But it's a good idea for me to be "platform-independent"..
5. compress the `coverage_info` map design by using the first and second columns together into a a key instead of two-level map. But again, how come this can speed up an already `O(1)` table query?

What else? Could anyone shed some lights on potential optimization options? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider loading this data into SQLite db, and querying SQLite to analyze/lookup your data. Time to import should be similar to time reading file from disk. At 100MB/s, it should be close to 100s, or roughly 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First you should check which part of the code takes most time. Probably it is either fgets/sscanf pair, or dealing with maps.   You should do this research *before* you ask the question here.  How?  Remove everything except sscanf from the loop, and see how much it takes now (you may want to read the smaller file, say 100M, for the test purpose).  Or use some profiling tool.  Then you should concentrate on the part which takes almost all the time.
2. Why do you read the line then parse it? Why not fscanf? You loop would start like this:

   while (true) {
   int rc = fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &func_id, &bb_id);
   if (rc != 2)
   break;
3. Yes, try using istream instead of file.
4. You have map of maps of tuples whose second and third elements are always 0. Why tuples, then? You should replace them to ints (`std::map<std::map<int>>`)

4a. After you use ints, you can simplify your whole loop to

```
while (fgets(line, len, fp)) {
    sscanf(line, "%d %d", &func_id, &bb_id);
    ++cmap[func_id][bb_id];
}
```

or, with fscanf,

```
while (true) {
    int rc = fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &func_id, &bb_id);
    if (rc != 2)
        break;
    ++cmap[func_id][bb_id];
}
```

It is because `std::map::operator[]` creates the element if it doesn't find one, and initializes it. Numbers are initialized to 0.

5. You have map of **maps**, but here:

   ```
      std::unordered_map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>> m;
      m[bb_id] = std::make_tuple(1, 0, 0);
      cmap[func_id] = m;
   ```

you assing **unordered_map**.  So it should convert unordered_map to map.

6. This thing

   ```
        auto c =std::get<0>(cmap[func_id][bb_id]);
        cmap[func_id][bb_id] = std::make_tuple(++c, 0, 0);
   ```

seems pretty inefficient, and should be simplified to `++std::get<0>(cmap[func_id][bb_id])` .

7. Do you compile with optimisations? (-O3 if you use Linux and g++).
8. Check if unordered_map is better than map. Check all variants: map of maps, map of unordered_maps, unordered_map of maps, unordered_map of unordered_maps.
9. If both numbers are 32-bit int, consider making one `unsigned long` from them (`z = ((unsigned long) x << 32) + y`, where x and y are unsigned longs). If you know that 0<=x<65536, 0<=y<65536, you might use `x << 16 + y`, while x and y are `unsigned`
10. After numerical sorting (`sort -d`, if I remember correctly), it might run faster, because it would use cache memory better. But sorting itself would take time.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I use `tuple` sine later on, I will need to update the other two elements in the tuple. In that case, can I still somewhat enjoy the handy `++cmap[func_id][bb_id];`?

Comment: The `fgets/sscanf ` part takes about 25% execution time while updating two-level maps take the rest. I changed this two-level map into one-level by using a `unit64_t` to subsume both integers and it becomes faster `15 mins --> 10 mins`

Comment: First read file and make map<uint_t, int>, then convert it to map<uint_t, tuple>.  It might be faster then working with map of maps of tuples in a huge loop.

Comment: If reading takes 25% time, it is worthwhile to check fscanf instead of fgets/sscanf.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is what I mostly follow to fine-tune my code. Right now it takes about 3 mins instead of the original 30 mins to process the log.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to read a large log files (around 10G)....

Consider separating the work in two phases:

- a batch processing which read the textual file, then fill some database with it. You could use [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) as your database, or some [NoSQL database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) (perhaps [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)). Of course, you need to learn a bit of [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) if you want to use some [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#RDBMS). You might consider using some indexed file library instead of a database, such as [Tokyo Cabinet](https://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/).
- the proper log processing would happen on the database itself.

You could also use better [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques. Parser generators such as [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) with [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) comes to mind. Notice that `sscanf` is not the fastest way to parse some textual file.

On Linux, don't expect to go faster than the [wc(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) or [cat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) or [cp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) programs. On my Debian/Sid desktop, ·`wc /usr/bin/emacs` takes 0.919 seconds  and `/usr/bin/emacs` has 32 megabytes (on SSD disk). So a 10 Gbytes file would take 300 times more.

Of course consider buying faster hardware, e.g. some SSD disk. Be aware of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

> Basically we have two columns, each column is an positive integer.

Columns and lines don't really exist, except with the *convention* that the `\n` newline character ends each line. A [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) is a *sequence* of bytes on most [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), sitting in some [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). Lines are just a *convention* related to using the <kbd>newline</kbd> character in files. Textual files are usually [UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) encoded.

For profiling and benchmarking purposes on Linux, consider using [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [perf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) and see [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You may need to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) in a specific way when compiling your C++ code.

Since you have freedom on the format of your log file, it might be written in some binary format, such as [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation). Then it might become more compact, so faster to read. You could also compress it (using [zlib](https://zlib.net/)). Consider also *splitting* your log file in smaller pieces (see [csplit(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html)): a hundred files of 100Mbytes each might be processed in parallel (in different threads or [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) on a [multi-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) machine).

Read also more [about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and notice that standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) may have their [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). The [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) could inspire you.

Read also a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: Basically the "log" file I generated is by instrumenting every basic block of a large software and profile it with some workload. I tried to make that "logger" as lightweight as possible and therefore speedup the profiling phase. Basically that part only has a `printf` to print out two integers each time.

Comment: Hmm.. If I iterately to fill in a db, not sure how slow the profiling phase becomes..